# HLS Android to Server

Tags: android, stream, http-live-streaming

Just wondering if there was a library to create (from device camera) a HLS stream (or stream over TCP) on the Android device.

Second question, if I want like 5 devices to connect to the HLS stream on the Android device, I ended up thinking that only a server could handle it.

So is there a way to create a HLS stream or TCP stream on Android device to then duplicate or forward the stream to the server so multiple devices could connect to the server to get the stream.

Wondering how Facebook Live / YouTube live are working because they should use something like this (stream over TCP)

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.